# Adjust Audio Panning

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

I'm creating a video player that plays on two external screens. For the two screens there is a button for the left and right screen. For each screen I want to pan the audio to the left and to the right respectively. I've added this into my btnRightPlay, however the audio still does not play on the right channel only. Does anyone have an advice on this? Do I need to add a buffer?

```
Pan.Right.Equals(10000);
```

Player codes for the video player

```
    public PlayerAvi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player.stretchToFit = true;
        player.uiMode = "none";
    }


    public override bool LoadVideo(string filePath)
    {
        _path = filePath;

        player.URL = _path;
        player.Ctlcontrols.stop();

        player.settings.balance = -100;
        waveOutSetVolume(0, 0x0000FFFF);
        return true;
    }


    public override bool PlayVideo()
    {
        player.Ctlcontrols.play();
        return true;
    }

    public override bool StopVideo()
    {
        player.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        return true;
    }

    public override bool PauseVideo()
    {
        player.Ctlcontrols.pause();
        return true;
    }

    public override bool ResumeVideo()
    {
        player.Ctlcontrols.play();
        return true;
    }


    public override bool ClearVideo()
    {
        StopVideo();
        _path = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Equals` is a comparison method. You cannot use it to assign a value. That's what `=` is for. Anyway, please add the relevant code how you play the sound. The above line could be anything.

Comment: I'm trying to pan the audio of the video if that is what you're referring to, instead of the sound.

Comment: So you have a control for video playback? Or do you use DirectShow? Or anything other than that? What object's `Pan` property are you accessing in the above code?

Comment: Yes i do have a control for video playback. I think i'm trying to access the player using DirectSound to pan the audio.

Comment: You won't tell us what control you have, will you?

Comment: I have quite a few controls for different formats of videos. If i show u the base player will it be enough?

Comment: Just show anything that might be relevant. Topmost, I am interested where the `Pan` property comes from.

Comment: I wrote the Pan property according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms817345.aspx although im not too sure what you mean as i have only been doing c# programming for a few months

Comment: Of what type is `player`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: You have a variable `player` in your code. Where and how do you declare it?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think it is part of the WMPlib.dll. It is done in sourcecode which controls all the play() stop() pause() functions of the video. So In my main control panel when i click on left button it will call out the video player to the left screen. And we tried setting the pan in the left button

Comment: So it's probably a wrapped `MediaPlayer`. The `MediaPlayer's` [`Balance` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.balance.aspx) can have values between -1 and 1. Try to set it to -1.